# My Icons in open weather map aren't changing

Tags: javascript

I cant get my icons to change, I know what I've done is a mess, please somebody help me.
I uploaded my icons in cloudinary, cause that's the only way I know to access images in stackblitz

```
fetch(api)
   .then(response => { return response.json(); })
   .then(data => {
       console.log(data.weather[0].icon)
       const {temp} = data.main;
       const {description} = data.weather[0];
       const {icon} = data.weather[0]; 
       temperatureDescription.textContent = description;
       temperatureDegree.textContent = Math.floor(temp - 273.15);
       locationTimezone.textContent = data.name;
       locationIcon = icon;
    })
    .then(function(){
        displayWeather();
        locationIcon.innerHTML = `<img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dybrtotf1/image/upload/v1634954533/icons/${icon}.png">`;
    });
})();
```

Comment: Let us know what happens so far.  And edit the question to add some more logging and tell us what the log output is at each stage.  We can't tell what's wrong based on what you have.

Comment: Looks like you used locationIcon different in two places <b>locationIcon = icon;</b> and 
<b>locationIcon.innerHTML = `<img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dybrtotf1/image/upload/v1634954533/icons/${icon}.png">`;</b> one of these have to be incorrect

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

##### The Problem

You've forgotten to return the `icon` from the second `then` and obviously didn't pass the returned data from the second `then` into the third `then` to use them.

##### How to fix it

return the `icon` or your whole data from the second `then` to use it on the `third` one:

```
fetch(api)
   .then(response => { return response.json(); })
   .then(data => {
       console.log(data.weather[0].icon)
       const {temp} = data.main;
       const {description} = data.weather[0];
       const {icon} = data.weather[0]; 
       temperatureDescription.textContent = description;
       temperatureDegree.textContent = Math.floor(temp - 273.15);
       locationTimezone.textContent = data.name;
       
       return icon  // -----> here
    })
    .then(function(icon){   // ----> pass the returned data to the function param to use it in this function
        displayWeather();
        locationIcon.innerHTML = `<img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dybrtotf1/image/upload/v1634954533/icons/${icon}.png">`;
    });
})();
```

##### Optionally

It seems that the `third` then changing is redundant, you can do the same with the second `then`, in this code snippet, I removed the unwanted parts:

```
fetch(api)
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(data => {
       const {temp} = data.main;
       const {icon, description} = data.weather[0];

       temperatureDescription.textContent = description;
       temperatureDegree.textContent = Math.floor(temp - 273.15);
       locationTimezone.textContent = data.name;
       locationIcon.innerHTML = `<img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dybrtotf1/image/upload/v1634954533/icons/${icon}.png">`
       
       displayWeather();

   })
   .catch(error => console.log(error)) 
})();
```

**Note:** always use the `catch` block with the asynchronous actions to catch the errors and do the proper actions in the failure case. here I just logged the error message, you can customize this section by adding the desired functionality.